# meteor, find whether user exists in mongodb document array or not?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This is my meteor code to search whether user exist in the array or not

```
var u_exist=Polls_Coll.findOne( {option1:{$elemMatch:{ids:"xxx"}}} );
```

My question is, How to know whether the statement returning something or not(user exist or not)

Comment: Wouldn't `u_exist` be `null` if it didn't find anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) will return only where one of the conditions supplied actually finds a match in the array. So if you don't get a document back then there was no match.

Also `findOne` is a single document. Modifiers such as .count() will not work on that. If you have more documents to be expected use `find` intstead. Also `findOne` not not make much sense without applying a unique identifier such as _id in the query. Without that you are almost certainly not getting what you want.

While useful for your purpose, findOne is not a good match with the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator. The reasoning is you can possibly get multiple results of the same document having the same set of array elements that matched the condition that you gave.

Buyer beware.

Comment: okay, i passed _id field too like this Polls_Coll.findOne({_id:"Wpv3dHYApDQZBdj8z"} ,{option1:{$elemMatch:{ids:'Sasikanth'}}} ) then how to know whether it returns something or not i want to check it in if condition, if it returns something i need to do some x if it not then y. How to check it?

Comment: Simply put, from `findOne` you will either get an object back or you will not, analog; "If it does not match then return nothing". So if there is `nothing` in the result then the `find` didn't match anything/